# Angular routing, templateUrl cannot find html file

Tags: angularjs

Been bashing my head against this for a couple of hours now and I'm out of ideas. I'm brand new to angular and trying to build a very basic application just to get a handle on it.

Relevant parts of the application are as follows:

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="weatherApp">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="vCentered">
                    <img src="assets/logo.png" id="logo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("weatherApp",  ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider)
          {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: "home.html";
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Hello.</h1>
```

Very basic. The issue is that, no matter what, I can't get the contents of home.html to show up when main.html is loaded. Note that the content *does* display when I use the following code in app.js:

```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    template: "Hello.";
  })
```

So it appears to be some kind of problem with templateUrl actually finding home.html.

I have put home.html everywhere. It's littered throughout my PC now on the off chance that templateUrl is hunting for it there but so far no luck in having anything load.

I have tried turning on Internet Information Services on my machine and putting the project into the inetpub/wwwroot folder but that hasn't helped. (Running Windows 10)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify both the index.html and home.html are in the same place? if you wanna skip the hassle go with `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
</script>`

Comment: main.html and home.html are in the same place.

I'd prefer to work out how to fix the problem for future use :)

Comment: I am assuming index.html is in the root of the project so what you need to do is place app.js in the same path as index.html and change `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay, I've tried that and it seems to have worked! Is there any way I can move app.js back to the js folder without breaking the links?

Comment: you need to set relative path from the app.js to the home.html so that will be `templateUrl: "../home.html"`(look one folder behind for index.html) can you try this? with app.js inside the JS folder also `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` change this in index.html

Comment: Yes that's pretty much done the trick. "../" takes you to the root of inetpub/wwwroot and then it's just a case of appending the name of the project folder. Thanks Naren, saved me a huge headache getting any worse :)

Comment: close the ticket if the problem is resolved, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Template url had to be set to

```
templateUrl: "../project%20name/home.html"
```

Also ensure that you access the project through localhost/main.html in the browser as that tripped me up at another point.